# Gvim 8 keeps crashing on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, gvim

I have installed the latest vim from Jonathon's `ppa:jonathonf/vim` but it keeps crashing even while opening a new file for editing with `:e`.

I could not find any solution on the net. Has anybody else experienced the same? How can I fix this?